# SQL conditional split data

Tags: sql, oracle

We need to split a column into 2, depending on the value of another column.

An example to be more clear.

Table:

```
GroupId|value|DebitOrCredit
1      |10   |C
1      |15   |D
2      |24   |D
2      |65   |C
```

Expected select results:

```
GroupId|credit|debit
1      |10    |15
2      |65    |24
```

We are using oracle.

Comment: What you have tried for this??

Comment: @IShubh I actually had no idea what I could try to do it. Or if it was doable. The answer of Tim does the job perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this via a basic pivot query:

```
SELECT
    GroupId,
    MAX(CASE WHEN DebitOrCredit = 'C' THEN value END) AS credit,
    MAX(CASE WHEN DebitOrCredit = 'D' THEN value END) AS debit
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY GroupId;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT GroupId, CASE WHEN DebitOrCredit = 'C' THEN value END AS Credit, 
CASE WHEN DebitOrCredit = 'D' THEN value END AS Debit
FROM table_name
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query-:

```
select GroupId,[C] as Credit,[D] as Debit
from YOUR_TABLE_NAME
PIVOT
(
sum(value) for DebitOrCredit in ([C],[D])
)t
```

SQL Server